# Join tables with the nearest date

Tags: mysql

installment_table:

| acc_no | installment_no | due_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 2022-04-22 |
| 12 | 2 | 2022-05-22 |
| 12 | 3 | 2022-06-22 |
| 12 | 4 | 2022-07-22 |
| 12 | 5 | 2022-08-22 |

transaction_table:

| acc_no | txn_date |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-04-22 |
| 12 | 2022-05-24 |
| 12 | 2022-06-18 |
| 12 | 2022-07-18 |
| 12 | 2022-08-25 |

resulting_table:

| acc_no | installment_no | due_date | txn_date | days_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | 2022-04-22 | 2022-04-22 | 0 |
| 12 | 2 | 2022-05-22 | 2022-05-24 | 2 |
| 12 | 3 | 2022-06-22 | 2022-06-18 | -4 |
| 12 | 4 | 2022-07-22 | 2022-07-18 | -4 |
| 12 | 5 | 2022-08-22 | 2022-08-25 | 3 |

I want to join the tables based on the account number and the nearest transaction date. Is there a way to do it in MySQL 8.0.37?

Comment: 8.0.37? not exists. Maybe, 8.0.27? if so then use LATERAL subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a *lateral join* to evaluate the days difference and select the minimum for each row:

```
select * 
from installment i,
lateral(
    select txn_date, DateDiff(txn_date, due_date) days_diff
    from transaction t
    where t.acc_no = i.acc_no
    order by Abs(DateDiff(txn_date, due_date))
    limit 1
)t;
```

See [Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=deca3eb10525a9d8d491038baa1fc5ae)